# How to get list of videos from Category in YouTube Api

Tags: swift, api, youtube, request, youtube-api

I try to receive a full list of videos which are part of the preferred category and I have a problem with it. First of all I check categories doing it:

```
func getCategories(complishion: ([CategoriesTitle]) -> Void ){
let youTubeURLCategoriesAdress = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories?part=snippet&regionCode=US&key=\(YOUTUBE_ACCESS_KEY)"
        Alamofire.request(.GET, youTubeURLCategoriesAdress).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response: Response<AnyObject, NSError>) in               
            switch response.result {
            case  .Success:
                if let json = response.result.value{
                    if let items = json["items"]{
                        print(items)
                        guard let categories: Array<CategoriesTitle> = Mapper<CategoriesTitle>().mapArray(items) else {
                            return
                        }
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            categoriesTitles(categories)
                        })
                    }
                }
}
```

in this case I receive all results. One example bellow:

```
etag = "\"5g01s4-wS2b4VpScndqCYc5Y-8k/nqRIq97-xe5XRZTxbknKFVe5Lmg\"";
id = 10;
kind = "youtube#videoCategory";
snippet =     {
    assignable = 1;
    channelId = "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ";
    title = Music;
};
```

and then I don't know how should I send request to the YT API and ask about full list of videos which are part of category 'Music' with id = 10 in this case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request below returns all videos within the Category "10" - you need to set the `type` to `video`

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&videoCategoryId=10&key=`{YOUR_API_KEY}

See https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&type=video&videoCategoryId=10&_h=1&